# Why did the defenders of the Tower of Joy fight Eddard?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

***Spoilers alert for those who haven't watched Season 6 Episode 3***

Lord Eddard Stark and companions fought to the death with three of Aerys's Kingsguard: Ser Gerold Hightower, Ser Arthur Dayne and Ser Oswell Whent, but why did they fight at all?

Eddard had come from the Sack of King's Landing so he could have told them that Aerys and Rhaegar were dead and that Robert now sat on the Iron Throne with the backing of the Lannisters.

Since Robert pardoned Ser Barristan Selmy he would be very likely to do the same for these three, especially as they hadn't even fought against him. They must also have known that Lyanna was in no danger from Eddard.

Answer (score 23):

**SPOILERS ALERT**

This answer will be composed entirely of spoilers. You have been warned. Read on your own hazard.

Editors, please do not go through the trouble of neutralizing words which may be spoilerish. The warning above should be enough.

---

Because they were supposedly:

> Charged by Prince Rhaegar to protect his paramour Lyanna Stark and
>  their child, Jon "Probably a Targaryen" Snow. Rhaegar was obsessed with an old prophecy of a prince that was promised and he may have believed that Jon was that prince, who shall be born with the Song of Ice and fire. Rhaegar thought of the child's security as imperative not just for the Targaryens but for whole humanity.

#### Change of Regime

This is what happened in the Tower:

> “I looked for you on the Trident,” Ned said to them.
>
> “We were not there,” Ser Gerold answered. **“Woe to the Usurper if we
> had been**,” said Ser Oswell.
>
> “When King's Landing fell, **Ser Jaime slew your king with a golden
> sword**, and I wondered where you were.”
>
> “Far away,” Ser Gerold said, “or **Aerys would yet sit the Iron
> Throne, and our false brother would burn in seven hells**.”
>
> “I came down on Storm's End to lift the siege,” Ned told them, and the
> Lords **Tyrell and Redwyne dipped their banners, and all their knights
> bent the knee to pledge us fealty**. I was certain you would be among
> them.”
>
> “**Our knees do not bend easily**,” said Ser Arthur Dayne.
>
> “**Ser Willem Darry is fled to Dragonstone, with your queen and Prince
> Viserys**. I thought you might have sailed with him.”
>
> “Ser Willem is a good man and true,” said Ser Oswell.
>
> “But not of the Kingsguard,” Ser Gerold pointed out. “**The Kingsguard
> does not flee**.”
>
> “Then or now,” said Ser Arthur. He donned his helm.
>
> **“We swore a vow,” explained old Ser Gerold.**
>
> Ned’s wraiths moved up beside him, with shadow swords in hand. They
> were seven against three.
>
> “And now it begins,” said Ser Arthur Dayne, the Sword of the Morning.
> He unsheathed Dawn and held it with both hands. The blade was pale as
> milkglass, alive with light.
>
> “No,” Ned said with sadness in his voice. “Now it ends.”

The Kingsguards never changed their loyalty, at least not the three at the tower. For them the dragons remained the King and Robert a usurper and they were honor bound to fulfill the last duty Prince of Dragonstone charged them with.

You can note in this dialogue:

1. Kingsguard refuse to refer to Robert as King and called him a usurper.
2. They profess loyalty to Aerys even then.
3. They refuse to bend knees to Robert despite almost all the realm doing it.
4. They refuse to flee in exile with their queen and princelings
5. It's a part of their honor-code! They do not flee,no matter what.
6. They swore a vow to defend the royal blood and do whatever the royal blood charges them with. They may have not liked Aerys after all, as they explained to Ned that they swore a vow to be loyal however and meant to keep it.

#### Why did Selmy do it?

Selmy did it because of his own feelings. He knew what Aerys was and Robert struck him as a better man. He however later regretted these feelings afterwards in life as he saw Robert become what he became.

Robert valued character and chivalry. From Eddard XII in AGOT:

> Robert could be merciful. Ser Barristan was scarcely the only man he
> had pardoned. Grand Maester Pycelle, Varys the Spider, Lord Balon
> Greyjoy; each had been counted an enemy to Robert once, and each had
> been welcomed into friendship and allowed to retain honors and office
> for a pledge of fealty. So long as a man was brave and honest, Robert
> would treat him with all the honor and respect due a valiant enemy.

Robert refused to kill Selmy for fighting against him. From *AGOT*:

> "Roose Bolton urged us to cut his throat, but your brother said, 'I
> will not kill a man for loyalty, nor for fighting well,' and sent his
> own maester to tend Ser Barristan's wounds." He gave the king a long
> cool look. "Would that man were here today."

So it must have been a nice shock for Selmy who had seen his liege lord Aerys burn his enemies for non-existent treasons. That's how Robert won his heart. However he eventually came to regret it.

From *ASOS, Daenerys V:*

> Ser Barristan had tears in his eyes. "I took Robert's pardon, aye. I
> served him in Kingsguard and council. Served with the Kingslayer and
> others near as bad, who soiled the white cloak I wore. Nothing will
> excuse that. I might be serving in King's Landing still if the vile
> boy upon the Iron Throne had not cast me aside, it shames me to admit.
> But when he took the cloak that the White Bull had draped about my
> shoulders, and sent men to kill me that selfsame day, it was as though
> he'd ripped a caul off my eyes. That was when I knew I must find my
> true king, and die in his service—"

#### Lyanna was not in any danger

That's true. But Jon would be. They were fighting for the Dragon inside Lyanna's womb mainly, not Lyanna herself.

Rhaegar may have known that first act of the rebels will be to wipe out all the potential claimants from the Royal House if they'd any hope to stabilize Robert's rule. Thus sensing a danger to the unborn child, he may have left the Kingsguard behind.

What orders did he give? Why did he do it? We do not know. We know however, it was Lyanna's words and Eddard's honor which protected Jon afterwards, not the white swords. Robert would have killed Jon if he had gotten so much as a whiff of who he really was.

#### What does GRRM say

GRRM has talked about this in [a correspondence with a fan](http://www.westeros.org/Citadel/SSM/Entry/Concerning_the_Tower_of_Joy):

> ***Q: The top three kingsguards, including the lord commander amd [sic] the best knight in ages, Ser Arthur Dayne are present there. Lyanna is in
> the tower, she asked Ned to promise him something. This, so says the
> general consensus us little Jon Snow, who is Lyanna's and Rhaegar's.
> No sense denying this ;)  However, what are the Kingsguards doing
> fighting Eddard? Eddard would never hurt Lyanna, nor her child. The
> little one would be safe with Eddard as well, him being a close
> relative. So I ask you, was there someone else with Lyanna and Jon?***
>
> **A:** You'll need to wait for future books to find out more about the Tower
> of Joy and what happened there, I fear.
>
> I might mention, though, that Ned's account, which you refer to, was
> in the context of a dream... and a fever dream at that. Our dreams are
> not always literal.
>
> ***Q: Also, did the Kingsguards know what was in the Tower?***
>
> **A:** Certainly.

Comment: You beat me to it with a placeholder answer ;)

Comment: @tobiasvl Don't let that hold you back. FGITW ;) A decent answer takes time to compile so take all the time you need.

Comment: Well, I wrote pretty much the same thing, only 8 minutes off :) I am removing my answer now, it adds nothing to yours.

Comment: Great answer as always. Covers everything we know now; I just wonder if what we know now is the whole story. The timing of the scream in the show, the amount of fresh blood in the book, the stationing of three of the best kingsguards here as if Rhaegar thought what happened here at this moment was more important than winning the war... got a sneaking feeling something was *happening* inside while the fighting went on, which Ned would want to stop; rushed forward *because* Ned had arrived. Could just have been a Cesarean, I guess...

Comment: @user568458 Indeed. Personally I am looking forward eagerly to know what actually went on in there. Hope it would come soon.

Comment: Yes it's a good answer but there remain some issues. Ser Gerold's justification is "We swore a vow" but the man they swore it to is dead and the man they probably preferred to serve (Rhaegar) is dead too. Selmy was as obsessed with honour as any other Kingsguard member but had no difficulty in bending the knee to Robert - whether he later regretted it or not. Aerys was a cruel lunatic. Supporting him after his death makes no sense.

Comment: As someone who is a two-time father and witnessed both births, I can tell you that it doesn't take a c-section to induce that type of screaming! Also, the show would have taken liberties in that area which may not have coincided with The George's intentions.

Comment: @TheMathemagician Well people have different ideas about loyalty. Dragons command a lot of respect and are considered the sole rightful Kings by the Loyalists such as KG. The men at ToJ didn't get to personally know Robert unlike Selmy and therefore couldn't have been influenced by his chivalry (Selmy himself later regretted it). Rhaegar and Aerys had died, Aegon had died (They however probably did not know) but Viserys was alive, Rhaella was alive and pregnant (They had no way of knowing about Dany's birth). They had a King still and his heir in womb of her mother.

Comment: @Mooz ha, I was actually thinking how *short* the screaming was (one very loud scream as opposed to lots of very loud protracted screaming and swearing!), and also that it coincided almost exactly with the guards losing the fight. Could be just for dramatic effect I guess, wouldn't be the first time (maybe in the TV show world, Dorne has a magical aura which causes contrived coincidences...)

Comment: @user568458 That's the best description of Show-Dorne that I've seen to date!